# Q: Getting "socket closed by remote peer" when trying to login/sign in to Quickblox server

Tags: quickblox

fellow stackoverflowians,

I'm working on a personal project to develop an iOS based chat app that uses Quickblox for its chat functionality.

Just recently we started getting the following error when trying to establish a connection to the Quickblox server and register or sign in a user.

TestApp[3975:76577] -[QBChat loginWithUser:] -> Connecting to Chat, hostName:chat.quickblox.com
TestApp[3975:76577] -[QBChat loginWithUser:] -> Chat server endpoint: chat.quickblox.com, User

Error Domain=GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=7 "Socket closed by remote peer" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Socket closed by remote peer}

Sometimes our app is able to log in.. and sometimes it just completely fails all of the time.  We cannot figure out if it's the Quickblox server that's having issues or if there's a fix in our code that needs to be added.

Can someone out there please shed some light?  We are about to release our app and this is a MAJOR hurdle preventing us from doing so.  We cannot get anyone from Quickblox to respond to our ticket.  We are an Advanced user (not Pro) and therefore our ticket hasn't been looked at.

Please see the below given code which we use for Quickblox registration and Quickblox sign in. See my inline comments also.

```
[self CallQBRegister:^{
// I am checking whether the user is already registered or not.
NSLog(@"Successfully registered..");  
}

// If already registered then the execution block will come to error block.
// there I am attempting to use Quickblox sign in process.
errorBlock:^{ 

NSLog(@"Already Registered, Active State is not Changed. Call QB Sign in");
[self callQBSignIn:^{
    NSLog(@"QB Login success");
} 
errorBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"QB Login Failure");
}];
}];
}
```

After that I am also checking if connection fails I am trying to reconnect with QBChat.

```
- (void)chatDidFailWithError:(NSInteger)code{
// re login here
[[QBChat instance] loginWithUser:self.currentUser];
}
```

When ever I am getting this error this code snippet will execute. The code which I am getting here it belongs to an error type, which I have defined in my code. The error what I am getting is "QBChatServiceErrorConnectionRefused".

can anyone help?
Quickblox.. are you listening?